# How to repeat the animation when scrolling the TextView with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

Swift 4: I'm trying to scroll the textView when tap an Button. Here are my codes:

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtViewStory: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    var scrollingTimer = Timer()

    @IBAction func scroll(_ sender: UIButton) {
        scrollingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.startScrolling), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        scrollingTimer.fire()

    }

    @objc func startScrolling(){
        var currentOffset = txtViewStory.contentOffset
        currentOffset = CGPoint(x: currentOffset.x, y: currentOffset.y + 1)
        txtViewStory.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
    }

}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Gif1]

The animation will stop when the TextView scrolls to the bottom. But I would like it to repeat scrolling again and again. Is there any way to get it work? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: On startScrolling Method just put condition like txtViewStory.contentOffset.y +  txtViewStory.bounds.heigt ==  txtViewStory.contentSize.height and reset content offset

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I'm new to Swift. Could you please put it more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

Very dirty code but should work ;>

```
@IBAction func scroll(_ sender: UIButton) {
    scrollingTimer.invaldiate()
    scrollingTimer = nil
    txtViewStory.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: currentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: false)

    scrollingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.startScrolling), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    scrollingTimer.fire()

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Michał. But it seems it doesn't work, there will be an error when adding "scrollingTimer = nil": Nil cannot be assigned to type 'Timer'. And it will stop when scrolling to bottom.

Comment: So remove that line or change the timer to be optional

Comment: Yes, I tried removing it. Removing the line won’t repeat the scrolling when it comes to the bottom.

Comment: Oh yes, it will not - It resumes it after button click

Comment: Thanks. Michal. Yes, it will resume when an button clicked. Could you please share some ideas on how to repeat scrolling the textView again and again even it comes to bottom?

Comment: UITextView inherits from UIScrollView. It means you can register as a delegate for UITextView and conform to UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. There you have method scrollViewDidScroll - check for content offset and if greater than some value run your timer again.

Comment: Also easier way is to check UITextView content offset inside your startScrolling method and there restart the timer.

Comment: Thanks for all the advices, Michal. Let me give it a try.